# Flutter Screen Auto Pop off when the data is empty but not null

Tags: flutter, dart

So Im trying to make a Screen which it will close when the return from api is empty

here's the code i've been trying to

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: GetOrga(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.data == null){
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )
                      )
                  );
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data == null ? 0 : snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    if (snapshot.data == ""){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                    return GestureDetector()
```

but it doesn't seem to work, It load and when the loading finished it just show empty screen.

here's the Flutter Output

```
flutter: []
```

Comment: Does `GetOrga` return a `String`?

Comment: @mddg yes it return a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you used the method [`hasData` of the `AsyncSnapshot`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) class which corresponds to your `snapshot`:

```dart
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  Navigator.pop(context)
}
```

I would also recommend you checked the `snapshot.connectionState` prop before accessing the data, as there may be an error or it may still be waiting for the response.

##### Update

Now that you've posted your API response, the condition `snapshot.data == ''` will never be `true` as it returns a list. You should use `snapshot.data == []` or cast it to a list and use the `isEmpty` operator.

Comment: it still doesn't do anything

Comment: In your question you say: This is the flutter output. What output are you printing?

Comment: it print the API response

Comment: Well if the API response is an empty list, then the if will never be true. Your api is returning a list, not a string.

Comment: aa I see, any solutions? both seems not to work

Comment: I should know more about your API